# generating an excel file using PHPExcel from a query against mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

I am testing out this code to generate an excel file in another folder from a query against  mysql table . It creates an empty excel file with no data in the cells . the file size however is not 0.

```
<?php
    require("mysql_conn.inc");
    require_once('PHPExcel.php');
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $query = "SELECT `col1`,`col2`";
    $query .= " FROM `table` limit 0,100";
    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);             
    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['col1']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['col2']);
        $rowCount++;
    }
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter->save('some_excel_file.xlsx');

    ?>
```

this is the code after I fixed the rowcount variable

```
<?php
require("mysql_conn.inc");
require_once('/PHPExcel.php');
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$query = "SELECT `col1`,`col2`";
$query .= " FROM `table` limit 0,100";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
$rowcount=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowcount, $row['col1']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowcount, $row['col2']);
    $rowcount++;
}
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('some_excel_file.xlsx');

?>
```

Comment: By using `$rowCount` the way you are, if `100` rows are returned by the query, then you're telling PHPExcel to store that data starting at row 100 until row 199, rows 1-99 will be empty..... is that what you're meaning to do?

Comment: Have you done basic debugging to show that your database query is returning data?

Comment: It works now thank you !